# Error due to action bar activity

Tags: java, android

Hey guys when i add any action to action bar in **android studio** it just says add app combat.....
When i added that it says to to change android to app and i changed that but when i run my application there is no action bar here is my xml and java code.
xml

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >
    <item
        android:title="search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
        android:text="search1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater i= getMenuInflater();
        i.inflate(R.menu.search_bar,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

app is running successfully but with no action bar

when i remove that function oncreateOptionMenu it still does not shows any action bar but it shows on my first activity actually this is menu of app here is code

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    }

    //@Override
    /*public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater i= getMenuInflater();
        i.inflate(R.menu.search_bar,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }*/
}
```

and here is manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Menu" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: when i remove that function oncreateOptionMenu it still does not shows any action bar but it shows on my first activity actually this is menu of app i added my manifest wel  though thank you for helping

Comment: change `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light` on your activity in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Post the exact message to allow a more specific response.

`showAsAction` should use your app namespace, i.e.:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...
app:showAsAction="always"
```

You should also make sure you're using an AppCompat theme in your app style.

Answer (score 0):

The appcompat themes remove the native ActionBar and use the support ActionBar.

You need to change

```
extends Activity
```

To

```
extends ActionBarActivity
```

You also need to change `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in your AndroidManifest.

Please see this blog post for more information: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Your welcome. Welcome to StackOverflow. If my answer resolved your problem don't forget to accept it. If not, let us know what other issues you have.